# How to restore a window without giving it focus using WPF (or interop)

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I need to **restore** ("un-minimize") a WPF window that has already been created but the window that's currently on top (not necessarily WPF) **can't lose focus or activation**. I have tried using all WIN32 functions I can find, to no avail. Getting really frustrated by now, would really appreciate any pointers and tips.

Obviously just changing to `WindowState.Normal` in WPF doesn't cut it as this makes the window receive focus and activation as-well. I have also tried all sorts of combinations with setting `Hidden` and `IsEnabled` while restoring.

I have tried WIN32 `SetWindowPos` with HWND_TOP, HWND_TOPMOST etc. but this function is not intended to restore windows and will only change position of already "displayed" windows.

Tried WIN32 `ShowWindow` and `SetWindowPlacement` but no luck there either. Tried a desperate attempt at adding a HwndHook to try and listen for `WM_SETFOCUS` and restoring focus to the original window but i only get zero for the last focused window handle..

**Edit - Solution with window extension after tip from Joel Lucsy:**

```
public static class RestoreWindowNoActivateExtension
{        
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 nCmdShow);

    private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;

    public static void RestoreNoActivate(this Window win)
    {
        WindowInteropHelper winHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(win);
        ShowWindow(winHelper.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code please?

Comment: I could post code if you really feel it's needed but since it's just a mess of attempts using different calls it's not really much to look at. Will post something if i do get it to work however..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `ShowWindow` passing the `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` flag.

Comment: I have really tried to accomplish this passing all combinations of parameters that I could think of. By now I'm confident that SetWindowPos can't be used to restore a window, but I would love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: How about ShowWindow with SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE?

Comment: +1 I edited your answer to include the correct answer. There's no point leaving the original answer there that doesn't work.

Comment: Tried out your suggestion but can't get it to work. The weird thing that happens is that the WindowState is changed from Minimized to Normal, but the window fail to show up on screen. Can someone confirm that ShowWindow should restore AND show the window? Will try and create a minimal example to test it out tonight..

Comment: Can confirm myself thatShowWindow with SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE should restore and show the window, without activating it or changing focus. It works perfectly well in a minimal example. Will have to figure out what goes wrong somewhere else. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I am trying to solve this same problem with a WPF app using MVVM.  When a timer expires, I want to restore the main window, so I send a message from the ViewModel to the View.  In the View, RestoreNoActivate() is called, but an exception is thrown: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."  Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated...

Comment: I think I found the answer in using this.Dispatcher.Invoke().